# Can not resolve domains in all programs except ping

Tags: networking, rhel, dns, resolv.conf

I've got a server for HPC usage, and it's RedHat. It appears to have a strange bug. I tried:

```
$ curl https://www.aliyun.com/ -vv
Couldn't resolve host 'www.aliyun.com'
```

I tried these as well:

- `wget https://www.aliyun.com/`
- `git clone https://github.com/my_username/my_repo`
- `telnet www.aliyun.com 80`
- `nc www.aliyun.com 80`, etc...

All of them give a similar error `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known.`. If I use the IP address directly, everything is OK. (Example: `wget https://140.205.34.3/ --no-check-certificate`) However, I can successfully `ping www.aliyun.com`.

I've tried `curl http://localhost/` and it works well (localhost is a domain specified in `/etc/hosts`).

Who is probably the culprit? Do you have any similar experience and provide any help?

`/etc/resolv.conf` attached here:

```
nameserver 11.11.4.1
nameserver 202.114.0.242
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 202.112.20.131
```

`uname -a` result:

```
Linux node111 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -a` result:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
Release:    6.2
Codename:   Santiago
```

`ip -a` result: (InfiniBand enabled)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:81:e1:15:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 11.11.0.111/16 brd 11.11.255.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::2e0:81ff:fee1:158d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:81:e1:15:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: ib0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2044 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 256
    link/infiniband 80:00:00:48:fe:80:00:00:00:00:00:00:46:d2:c9:20:00:00:38:b1 brd 00:ff:ff:ff:ff:12:40:1b:ff:ff:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.0.111/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global ib0
    inet6 fe80::46d2:c920:0:38b1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 52:54:00:7f:dc:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:7f:dc:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**NOTE:** I don't have root privilege to the machine.

Content of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# The entry '[NOTFOUND=return]' means that the search for an
# entry should stop if the search in the previous entry turned
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Valid entries include:
#
#   nisplus         Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#   nis         Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#   dns         Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#   files           Use the local files
#   db          Use the local database (.db) files
#   compat          Use NIS on compat mode
#   hesiod          Use Hesiod for user lookups
#   [NOTFOUND=return]   Stop searching if not found so far
#

# To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis

passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files     

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files

netgroup:   files ldap

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files ldap
aliases:    files nisplus
```

#### EDIT #1

```
$ getent hosts www.microsoft.com
218.58.101.49 e13678.ca.s.tl88.net www.microsoft.com www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net www.microsoft.com-c-3.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net

$ getent hosts www.aliyun.com
2400:3200:1300::3e v6wagbridge.aliyun.com.gds.alibabadns.com www.aliyun.com www-jp-de-intl-adns.aliyun.com www-jp-de-intl-adns.aliyun.com.gds.alibabadns.com v6wagbridge.aliyun.com
```

#### EDIT #2

`getent hosts www.aliyun.com` works pretty good, but `getaddrinfo` reports `name or service not known`. (Tested in [this simple C program](https://pastebin.com/JYAabCaT))

#### EDIT #3

I've tried `dig` and it seems that the DNS server `11.11.4.1` is not working for Global Internet. Here's what I found.

```
$ dig @11.11.4.1 www.aliyun.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3-RedHat-9.7.3-8.P3.el6 <<>> @11.11.4.1 www.aliyun.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 37272
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.aliyun.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 11.11.4.1#53(11.11.4.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 20 14:48:37 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32

$ dig @1.1.1.1 www.aliyun.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3-RedHat-9.7.3-8.P3.el6 <<>> @1.1.1.1 www.aliyun.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64269
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.aliyun.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.aliyun.com.     113 IN  CNAME   www-jp-de-intl-adns.aliyun.com.
www-jp-de-intl-adns.aliyun.com. 293 IN  CNAME   www-jp-de-intl-adns.aliyun.com.gds.alibabadns.com.
www-jp-de-intl-adns.aliyun.com.gds.alibabadns.com. 113 IN CNAME xjp.wagbridge.aliyun.aliyun.com.
xjp.wagbridge.aliyun.aliyun.com. 89 IN  CNAME   xjp-adns.aliyun.com.
xjp-adns.aliyun.com.    89  IN  CNAME   xjp-adns.aliyun.com.gds.alibabadns.com.
xjp-adns.aliyun.com.gds.alibabadns.com. 89 IN A 47.88.251.164

;; Query time: 223 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 20 14:48:39 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 256
```

Comment: `/bin/ping` is usually installed as suid binary, so it has root privileges when asking to resolve hostnames. Check netfilter (iptables) settings or permissions on `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @IporSircer `/etc/resolv.conf` has permission `-rw-r--r--`. `/bin/ping` is truly a suid binary. I can not access iptables settings without root... That's a difficult problem...

Comment: Have a look at http://dnsviz.net/d/www.aliyun.com/W3jfVw/dnssec/  it shows multiple errors and warnings in your DNS configuration. You should first resolve that before doing anything else.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Aliyun is a large cloud computing company in china... Other domain doesn't work as well (for example: www.microsoft.com, www.baidu.com, etc)

Comment: *Aliyun is a large cloud computing company in china...* which does not exclude them from DNS errors... see the link given,  their setup does not look good at all, and I would never loose time debugging DNS problems when I see such kind of setup. I also think you may have an IPv6/IPv4 kind of problem and I would never recommend mixing nameservers like in your `resolv.conf` example. And to diagnose DNS problems there is only one relevant command: `dig`

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/hosts`? What do you get as reply of `dig @11.11.4.1 www.aliyun.com` (or other names). Try with and without `+tcp`, with and without `+6` and then changing the nameserver you hit, the IP after the `@`. Also are you really using IPs in the range 11.0.0.0/8? These are allocated to the DoD so you can not just hijack them and hope things will work. Private IPs should be 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks! Now I'm sure that the DNS server `11.11.4.1` is not working. See the `EDIT #3` in the question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This confuses a lot of people but the `ping` command has its own integrations with the `/etc/resolv.conf` file whereas the other tools you mentioned utilize the Name Server Switch facility. You can see this if you run  an `strace <cmd>` and analyze the output of the libraries that the commands are interacting with.

For example, here's `ping`:

```
$ strace ping -c 3 www.aliyun.com |& grep -E "ns|resolv"
open("/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

And here's `curl`:

```
$ strace curl -v www.aliyun.com |& grep -E "ns|resolv"
open("/lib64/libnss3.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libnssutil3.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libnspr4.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("47.88.251.161")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("47.88.251.161")}, [16]) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(55876), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.2.15")}, [16]) = 0
```

You're probably wondering, but wait, they're both showing a call to `libresolv`, so what's the issue? The reason that `curl` even knows to call to `libresolv` is because it was directed to do so. Why? Because of this file:

```
$ grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

The `hosts:` reference in this file tells tools that make calls to NSS (Name Server Switch) that they should consult with `files` first, then call into `dns` second.

The `files` reference means to use the `/etc/hosts` file, the `dns` option means to consult `/etc/resolv.conf` for a DNS nameserver and look up the hostname there.

#### Your issue

So your issue is most likely due to your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file is missing the `dns` entry as I've shown above.

#### What executables use NSS?

You can look at executables using `readelf` which shows what shared libraries an executable requires.

```
$ type -f curl
curl is /bin/curl

$ readelf -d /bin/curl | grep -i shared
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcurl.so.4]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsmime3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnss3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnssutil3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libplds4.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libplc4.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnspr4.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]

$ type -f ping
ping is /bin/ping

$ readelf -d /bin/ping | grep -i shared
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcap.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libidn.so.11]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.10]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libresolv.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

A similar method can be used with `ldd`:

```
$ ldd /bin/ping|grep -E "ns|resolv"
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fd144d40000)

$ ldd /bin/curl|grep -E "ns|resolv"
    libnss3.so => /lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f9795413000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f97951e4000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f9794b9d000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9792067000)
```

#### DNS appears to be working

If you're able to run these commands and they work:

```
$ getent hosts www.google.com
216.58.193.164  www.google.com

$ getent hosts www.aliyun.com
47.88.198.17    xjp-adns.aliyun.com.gds.alibabadns.com www.aliyun.com
```

Then try using `opennssl` to see if you can connect to these services:

```
$ true | openssl s_client -connect www.aliyun.com:443
depth=2 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
depth=0 C = CN, ST = ZheJiang, L = HangZhou, O = "Alibaba (China) Technology Co., Ltd.", CN = *.aliyun.com
 0 s:/C=CN/ST=ZheJiang/L=HangZhou/O=Alibaba (China) Technology Co., Ltd./CN=*.aliyun.com
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
 1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
subject=/C=CN/ST=ZheJiang/L=HangZhou/O=Alibaba (China) Technology Co., Ltd./CN=*.aliyun.com
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
```

#### References

- [Name Server Switch - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch)

Comment: @RecolicKeghart - so DNS looks to be working then.  I suspect something with either the DNS server(s) you're using or the  SSL certificates. You're in China? How are you sure it isn't something that is being done by your internet service provider?

Comment: I wrote a [simple C program](https://pastebin.com/JYAabCaT) to call `getaddrinfo` and it returns `name or service not known`. And `openssl` returns `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known connect:errno=0`

Comment: @RecolicKeghart - seems like a DNS or SSL issues then still. What does this show for you? `echo -e "TRACE / HTTP/1.1\nHost: xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com\n\n" | nc xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com 80 `?

Comment: Firewall as well - `iptables -L -n`?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/117723

Comment: I can not access `iptables -L -n` without root privilege.. the `nc` command returns `nc: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`. Maybe I have to debug the problem as root...