# DNS resolution no longer consistent on Centos 7 (ping is no DNS test)

Tags: centos, dns

My Centos 7 system has worked for years. Now I am facing a strange issue connected to DNS resolution. It works as expected when using `ping`, but it fails as soon as I want to use `curl`. Should they not both use the same resolver? What could be the reason for the discrepancy?

```
# ping homeserver.fritz.box
PING homeserver.fritz.box (192.168.178.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from homeserver.fritz.box (192.168.178.52): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms
64 bytes from homeserver.fritz.box (192.168.178.52): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
64 bytes from homeserver.fritz.box (192.168.178.52): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
^C
--- homeserver.fritz.box ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.098/0.115/0.146/0.024 ms
# curl -v http://homeserver.fritz.box
* Could not resolve host: homeserver.fritz.box; Unknown error
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: homeserver.fritz.box; Unknown error
#
```

BTW, I am running these commands on the machine with IP 192.168.178.52, but this may be meaningless.

Edit: Meanwhile I found out there was no entry in /etc/hosts matching the server name. Adding it solved my problem, yet I still do not understand why ping was able to resolve the name. And I am clueless as of what to look at.

Comment: You could check to see what's in your "hosts" entry in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file and take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463357/can-not-resolve-domains-in-all-programs-except-ping/463403#463403

Comment: Oh, rats! the first sentence already mentions that ping is not suitable to test name resolution. It says: This confuses a lot of people but the ping command has its own integrations with the /etc/resolv.conf file whereas the other tools [...] utilize the Name Server Switch facility.